# Eclipse ADT Bug?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

Nothing appears in the area to add string values after I added a string literal in graphical view of strings.xml.
Is this **eclipse Juno** Bug ?
How to resolve it?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest release and then see what happens.

Comment: I have updated my eclipse. Still problem persists.

Comment: Mac, Windows or Linux OS?

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Eclipse doesnt need install or uninstall.. it directly runs on Windows